# How can I include these 4 variables into my code in R

Tags: r, dataset, statistics, visualization

Here's a glimpse of the dataset I'm using.

SpeedDating dataset:

[image]

The data set I'm using is `SpeedDating`. My goal is to look at whether or people prefer to date each other of the same race. I was working with the variables `DecisionM`, `DecisionF`, `RaceM` and `RaceF`, wherein the Decision variables, 1 = yes and 0 = no to a second date, with my end goal being able to visualize this in some ggplot chart. My code so far is as shows:

```
test <- SpeedDating %>%
  filter(DecisionM, DecisionF) %>%
   group_by(RaceM == "Caucasian") %>%
  group_by(RaceF == "Caucasian") %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count == max(count))
test
```

I know I'm doing it wrong here but I don't know where to start, I thought about combining the two Race variables but I'm sure how to that right now either. Any help is appreciated. If you have any questions for me please ask.